# Can I get data from firebase firestore without putting it in a list in flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

Is it possible to get data from firebase firestore without putting it in a list/listview in Flutter? How?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do like this to get data from firebase.

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc(userId).get().then((DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
  if (documentSnapshot.exists) {
    print('Document data: ${documentSnapshot.data()}');
  } else {
    print('Document does not exist on the database');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**Yes**

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').get().then()
.then((value) {
//in value you have saved the data on it and you can use it whenever you want 
});
```